# Show uncorrelated, with Brownian motions

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

> I have $W_t$ is a Brownian Motion and $$B_t :=W_t-\int_0^t \frac{W_u}{u}du$$ is also a Brownian Motion. I have to show that these two are uncorrelated.

I know for Brownian uncorrelated is equivalent to $E[W_tB_t]=0$.

I have at this point 
$$
E\left[W_t^2\right]-E\left[W_t\int_0^t\frac{W_u}{u}du\right]=t-....?$$

So i don't know how i compute the second expected value but i know it should be $t$. 
Can anybody help me?

Comment: not sure, perhaps we can approximate the integral with a sum and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Ito's formula gives
$$
d(B_tW_t)=B_tdW_t+W_tdB_t+dW_tdB_t=(W_t+B_t)dW_t+(1-(W_t^2/t))dt.
$$
Therefore, for a local martingale $m_t$,
$$
E(B_tW_t)=Em_t+\int_0^t1-(EW_s^2)/s\,ds.
$$
The second integral is $0$, it remains to see that $m_t$ is a true martingale. Can you finish from here?